# SQLAnywhere: Cursor getting closed after executing a DDL statement

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere

Having this code here:

```
DECLARE @rowfoo integer
DECLARE @query varchar (32000)

SET @query = 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testprocedure AS
            BEGIN
                print ''Just a dummy text''
            END'

DECLARE test_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT row_num FROM sa_rowgenerator(1, 31, 1)

OPEN test_cursor
    FETCH NEXT test_cursor into @rowfoo
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        execute(@query)
        FETCH NEXT test_cursor into @rowfoo
    END
CLOSE test_cursor
DEALLOCATE test_cursor
```

I've recognized, that the cursor is getting closed after the `execute(@query)` statement. Based on what I've found so far it's because of implicit commit done for DDL statements. 
As I need to create number of procedures via a script, is there any work around for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening a cursor, there is the `WITH HOLD` preventing the issue. So

```
DECLARE @rowfoo integer
DECLARE @query varchar (32000)

SET @query = 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testprocedure AS
            BEGIN
                print ''Just a dummy text''
            END'

DECLARE test_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT row_num FROM sa_rowgenerator(1, 31, 1)

OPEN test_cursor WITH HOLD
    FETCH NEXT test_cursor into @rowfoo
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        execute(@query)
        FETCH NEXT test_cursor into @rowfoo
    END
CLOSE test_cursor
DEALLOCATE test_cursor
```

Is working well for my case. As an alternative `close_on_endtrans` option could also be switched either for session or public.